How can we calculate this integral if this diverges?
I know that: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x} \, dx=\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)
$$ where $s \notin \mathbb{Z}
$
Which we know is the Euler reflection formula for the Gamma function and evaluates to :$$\frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi s)}$$
But when I plotted this curve on Desmos I found that area under this curve is divergent.
Then how we can calculate this integral.
Here is curve for $s=2.5$ . According to the formula it should evaluate to :
$$\frac{\pi}{\sin (\frac{5\pi}{2})}=\pi$$

Here is for $s=3.5$ which should evaluate to:
$$\frac{\pi}{\sin (\frac{7\pi}{2})}=-\pi$$
What I am doing wrong here?

In the case $s=5/2$ and $s=7/2$, the integral is divergent. The formula makes sense when the integral is convergent. For example, when $s=5/2$ you have:
$$\frac{x^{3/2}}{1+x}\sim x^{1/2} \quad \text{as} \quad x\to +\infty  $$
so the integral is divergent.

But why? There is no condition on s except it cannot be an integer.

And 1 more thing. Suppose we take where s=-0.5 which clearly converges. But when we plot we see the area under the curve is positive. but acc to the formula it evaultes to -$\pi$

@PrinceYadav why it "clearly converges" when $s=-1/2$?

Because s-1 becomes -1.5. so the expression becomes $$\frac{x^{-1.5}}{1+x}\approx
\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$$ which clearly converges.
Take s=-2.5 or s=-4.5 .These do converge and the area is positve but formula gives it negative.

@PrinceYadav you forgot to study the behavior near $x=0$

Yes my mistake. So where exactly can I use this formula?

@PrinceYadav See this
